# Enumeration and 2D arrays in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, enums, enumeration

I'm currently working on some code in Python, and I have the following enumerations:

```
#Enumeration - matter type
matterType = ['matter', 'antimatter']
enumMatterType = enumerate(matterType)

#Enumeration  - flavor
flavor = ['electron', 'mu', 'tau']
enumFlavor = enumerate(flavor)
```

I've also created a 2D array:

```
alpha = [[alpha_electron, alpha_anti_electron], 
        [alpha_mu, alpha_anti_mu], 
        [alpha_tau, alpha_anti_tau]]
```

Which is supposed to be an array of constants that I have defined earlier. I'm using these constants in an equation, but I'm referencing them as `alpha[0][0]` or `alpha[0][1]`, etc. I feel like when someone looks at my code, they would understand it better if I had something like `alpha[matter][electron]` or `alpha[antimatter][electron]`. Is there any way to use the enumeration from earlier to define my variables from the array like this? How can I use enumeration with arrays in general? How would I be able to write my alpha values with the enumeration? Please let me know if any part of this does not make sense - I would be happy to clarify.

Comment: `alpha[matter][electron]` wouldn't be possible, because they would have to be fixed values for `matter` and `electron`. Consider a dictionary with a tuple key?

Comment: I think you’re looking for `enum.IntEnum`?

Comment: These are not arrays, they are *lists*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider a dictionary with tuple keys:

```
matterType = ['matter', 'antimatter']
flavor = ['electron', 'mu', 'tau']

alpha = [['alpha_electron', 'alpha_anti_electron'], 
        ['alpha_mu', 'alpha_anti_mu'], 
        ['alpha_tau', 'alpha_anti_tau']]

ref_dict = {}
for x, pair_item in enumerate(flavor):
    for y, item in enumerate(matterType):
        ref_dict[(item, pair_item)] = alpha[x][y]
```

Now let's say I want "matter" and "mu":

```
In[60]: ref_dict[('matter', 'mu')]
Out[60]: 'alpha_mu'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a set of enumeration constants, that's exactly what the [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) module is for.

In your case, you want enumeration constants that have an integer value, so you can use them as indexes into a list. For that, you want [`IntEnum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#intenum):

```
from enum import IntEnum

class MatterType(IntEnum):
    MATTER = 0
    ANTIMATTER = 1

class Flavor(IntEnum):
    ELECTRON = 0
    MU = 1
    TAU = 2
```

And now, instead of this:

```
alpha[0][0]
```

… you can write this:

```
alpha[MatterType.MATTER][Flavor.ELECTRON]
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the easy way I do is:

```
from enum import Enum
ENUM_VAR_NAME = Enum('ENUM_VAR_NAME',['var1',var2',var3'])

ENUM_VAR_NAME.var1
```